# Integration of a footer menu in a Joomla! template?

Tags: joomla, menu, footer

I didn't find the answer of my question in stackoverflow, so excuse me if this is a duplicate.

I need a step by step guide on How to create a footer menu in Joomla!, and HOW TO USE THIS MENU LATER. I actually created the menu but I don't know how to use it in a template. Please note that I'm new to Joomla! and just use it for the SEO it has.

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A footer menu is just like any other menu, same concept.

First of all, you need to create the markup in your **index.php** in your template folder like so:

```
<div id="footer">
   <jdoc:include type="modules" name="footer" />
</div>
```

Then, in the Joomla backend, create a new Menu type and call it something like "Footer Menu". Once done, start creating a few menu items and assign them to the menu type you created before.

Then:

1. Create a new module,
2. Set the type to **menu**
3. Open the module in the Module Manager and on the right hand side in the parameters, there will be an option to select which menu you wish to use. Choose the one you have created.
4. Set the position to **footer** (assuming that is the name of the position you're using for the footer. If not then use whatever is required)
5. Publish the module and assign to all menu items
6. Save

On your website you will see the menu you have created, it will look rather bad but you can now start styling it using CSS to make it look better

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks to you, I now have an awesome footer on my website :)